# Prove that $y(x) = x^n\int_0^{\pi}\cos(x \cos\varphi)\sin^{2n}\varphi d\varphi$ solves $x^2y'' + xy' + (x^2 -n^2)y = 0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let we have $$y(x) = x^n\int_0^{\pi}\cos(x \cos\varphi)\sin^{2n}\varphi  d\varphi$$

How to check that $y(x)$ satisfies following differential equation :
$$x^2y'' + xy' + (x^2 -n^2)y = 0$$

Comment: diffentiate $y(x)$ and plug-in the differential equation

Comment: What attempts have you made to solve the problem? Can you calculate $y'$?

Comment: you might need to integrate by parts

Comment: but because you are an experienced user who puts no effort in his question i vote to close

Comment: these are like Chebyshev polynomials.

Comment: @MyGlasses It is Bessel functions. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context: It is the differential equation of a multiple of Bessel function $J_n$ (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html) where this function is under a certain integral representation that can be found [formula (10.9.4) here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9).

It suffices to check that you can **differentiate under the integral sign**, i.e., (not taking into account the first $x^n$) that you can write:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_0^{\pi}\cos(x \cos\varphi)\sin^{2n}(\varphi)  d\varphi=\int_0^{\pi}\dfrac{d}{dx}\cos(x \cos\varphi)\sin^{2n}(\varphi)  d\varphi$$

$$=-\int_0^{\pi}\sin(x \cos\varphi)\cos\varphi\sin^{2n}(\varphi)  d\varphi$$

See [theorem 11.3 in this document](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf).

Can you proceed from that?

An advice: start with $n=1$.